# string concatenation in c++

Tags: c++, string, concatenation

Previously, I was using append function to concatenate strings.
However, since doing so requires multiple lines of unnecessary codes, I wanted to try out '+' operator instead. Unfortunately, it didn't go well...

```
bool Grid::is_available(int x, int y) const
{
    if (x < 0 || x >= dim[1] || y < 0 || y >= dim[0])
        throw std::invalid_argument("is_available(" + x + ", " + y + "): Invalid coordinate input.");
    return occupancy[x][y] == AVAILABLE;
}
```

The error that I got was "'+': cannot add two pointers" with the code C2110. 
All the solutions for this problem said to concatenate one on each line.
Are there actually no way to concatenate multiple strings in C++ in one line? I had no problem with this in C# before.

Comment: You're concatenating two string literals. The + operator will work on two `std::string`s or one `std::string` and one `char*`.

Comment: Also, you're adding a string literal to an integer, which won't work.

Comment: This works: `auto foo = std::string{ "Hello" } + " world!";`

Comment: `Previously, I was using append function to concatenate strings.`  Why?  Seriously though, are you designing a grid of some sort, or trying to create your own String routines?  If it's the former, just use `std::string` and get going with the rest of the program.

Comment: Not sure what the relevance of C# is?

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie: I'm not the best person to handle this matter... I've started learning this only a few weeks ago.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `std::to_string()` to convert your integers:

```
bool Grid::is_available(int x, int y) const
{
    if (x < 0 || x >= dim[1] || y < 0 || y >= dim[0])
        throw std::invalid_argument(
            "is_available(" + std::to_string(x) + ", "
                + std::to_string(y) + "): Invalid coordinate input.");
    return occupancy[x][y] == AVAILABLE;
}
```